# Jquery gallery working in Chrome after pressing ENTER a 2nd time, whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

This is the [link](http://globalelitenetworking.net/1clickday_responsive/),  the Jquery gallery works well in firefox but in chrome and safari, on a first time click it doesnt show up only after you press enter for a 2nd time in the URL, any ideas what is wrong?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Its working, the problem is that it is not showing because ul have 0 height and overflow is hidden
Add height to #slider, it will be visible

Comment: thanx, it kind of worked ut something else didnt work...., end of the story the best solution is to look for another slider. Thank You anyways!